# Send new rows of Snowflake table as JSON as HTTP POST request?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a data pipeline that takes new row inserts to a Snowflake table, transforms it to JSON and sends it to another API as a HTTP Post request.

The use case here is I am taking a table of transactions and I want to log new transactions in a separate service which receives events via their API.

I think Streams will solve half the puzzle in that it gives me the changes (or inserts) to my table but is there a service or feature that can take this table, do the necessary transformations and send it along to a separate API as a HTTP Post request?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: What is sending the changes? You may be better adding your streaming there rather than after it hits the database

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use external functions.

To send the results of a query to an external function, I chose to encode it as an array of arrays:

```sql
select prophetize(array_construct(
        array_agg(value::float) within group(order by date)
        , array_agg(date::date) within group(order by date))::string) str
from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1)));
```

For a complete example, see what I did here:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/forecasts-in-snowflake-facebook-prophet-on-cloud-run-with-sql-71c6f7fdc4e3

As you say, streams will help you get all incoming changes to send.